# Problem regarding master pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a simple master page (master.aspx), which has 3 link buttons namely HomeLBTn-which redirects the users to home.aspx, LoginLBtn-to login.aspx, RegisterLBtn-to Register.aspx

Every page in my project inherits the master page. And home.aspx also inherits the master.aspx, but i don't want the home.aspx to inherit the HomeLBtn, I want it to inherit the remaining 2 LBtn's, but not the HomeLBtn. How can i incorporate this condition into Home.aspx

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to find the control in the MasterPage and set its visibility to false:

```
Page.Master.FindControl("HomeLBtn").Visible = False
```

This would be done in the Page_Load (or some other lifecycle event) on the page that shouldn't show the Home button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in the master page ( Check what the child page is )

```
 //If the child page is viewing an order then disable the new request button       
 if (this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page is OrderView)       
 { 
      base.RemoveMenuItem("New Request", mnuSettings);        
 }
```

Note: base.RemoveMenuItem is a method of my base page

http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-hide-show-controls-on-master.html

Another option would be to add a property to the child page and master page and use session data to hide and show buttons.

eg. in Child Page:

```
protected MyCustomMasterPage CustomMasterPage
{
  get
  {
     return this.Master as MyCustomMasterPage;
  }
}
```

In your master page you could have a session variable you can set to hide and show the buttons

```
public bool HomeVisible
{
   get
   {
      return (bool) Session["HomeVisible"]; 
   }
   set
   {
      Session["HomeVisible"] = value;
   }
}
```

You would then check the HomeVisible property when loading the master page to show / hide the button. You can then set this from the child page.

```
this.MyCustomMasterPage.HomeVisible = false;
```

Maybe not the best ways but they work

Comment: this isn't scalable. What if he has more pages that need this? It's best to do it on each page with a specific need. You add overhead when doing this on the master page because pages that dont have special needs still have to run this logic

Comment: I agree, Another option would be to add a property to the child pages to cast the master page and check there. Ill add it to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In master.aspx, define Register and Login link buttons, and a content placeholder for where the Home button would go. Then have Home.aspx inherit master.aspx. Then create a 2nd master page (master2.aspx) that inherits from master.aspx. In master2, add the Home link button in the content placeholder, and have your other pages inherit from master2.